# PowerShell Returning "False" for Test-Path "C$\Program Files (x86)"

Tags: powershell, path, output, copy-item

When attempting to copy a file to a directory via-

```
Copy-Item $Source -Destination "C$\Program Files (x86)" -Recurse -EA Continue -EV +PushFailures
```

I'm unable to do so. So I tried testing to see if PowerShell is even seeing the directory-

```
Test-Path "C$\Program Files (x86)"
```

and it returns "False" even though it's clearly there.

What am I doing wrong here and how can I correct it? I read about "$env:programfiles" although I'm not sure how to implement that into a string variable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not used to using `C$\Program Files (x86)` in that context since it is usually referenced in remote administration shares like `\\Computername\C$\Program Files (x86)`. Did you mean to just use `C:\Program Files (x86)`?

Part of the issue is that `$` is a reserved character in PowerShell and need to be escaped in strings. Two ways to do this with what you have:

```
-Destination "C`$\Program Files (x86)"
-Destination 'C$\Program Files (x86)'
```

I feel though that this will not work. If you just want the local path of program files then this would help you include the Environment variable as you suggested

```
-Destination "$env:ProgramFiles"
-Destination "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}"
```

If the path contain both string elements and variables then you need to ensure that they are expanded properly by using a sub-expression

```
-Destination "$($env:ProgramFiles)\Internet Explorer"
```

Comment: I actually am, in the end, using it in the context of a remote share. The actual copy command uses "\\$station\$rootdestination" as the destination where "$station" indicates the network PC to copy the file to.

Comment: I tried the following-
`Test-Path "$env:ProgramFiles" `
`Test-Path "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}" `

And they all work. However, when trying to concatnate a directory at the end, it fails-
    `Test-Path "$($env:ProgramFiles)" += "\SUMMIT WOC" `
    `Test-Path "$($env:ProgramFiles)\SUMMIT WOC"`

Comment: THIS actually ended up working-

"${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Directory"

Thank you for all your guidance and help!

Comment: @Brady Sounds like you need to be sure what architecture your computer is. `$env:ProgramFiles` would typically resolve to ``C:\program files\`` on 32-bit and 64-bit hosts. Whereas `${$env:ProgramFiles(x86)}` would be `C:\Program Files (x86)` on a 64-bit host.

Comment: @Martt My issue now seems to be that it won't accept this as a variable when trying to apply it to a network directory, if that makes sense. Like so:

Variable - `$Destination = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Directory"'
Test 1, success- 'Test-Path "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Directory"'
Test 2, success- 'Test-Path $destination'
Test 3, FAIL- 'Test-Path "\\$station\$destination"'
Test 4, FAIL- 'Test-Path \\$station\"${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Directory"`

Any ideas?

Comment: `$env:ProgramFiles(x86)` is a reference to a local environmanet variable and will not translate to remote hosts. ``"\\$computer\C`$\Program Files(x86)\$Directory"`` would be more of what you are looking for.